# How to set shortcut key to open query in ms access. can some body explain clearly

Tags: ms-access-2007

How to set shortcut key to open query in ms access. can some body explain clearly. how to set shortcut key to already designed qureiess

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a command button to open the query, then in the Command button caption add & and the short cut key you want to use to open the query.

e.g if a command button's caption is Run Query , you can change it to
&NRun Query ,tis will ensure that Alt and N keys will open the query.

Check the images i attached.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

[image: Step 6]

[image: Final Outcome]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You gave me solution. I am searching answer in google for 1 year. thanks for the solution

Comment: Then please mark as answered.

Comment: Can the OP with a reputation of less than 15, mark as answered or upvote?

Comment: @SolaOshinowo, yes they can accept answer. But, they cannot vote.